# Work to overcome adhesion of a liquid to a solid

Tags: bond, intermolecular-forces, adhesion

I'm interested in the van Der Waals force of a liquid adhered to a solid. For example, if you spray some water on a vertical piece of glass, the little droplets with adhere to the window rather than be pulled down by gravity.

How does one calculate the energy of that bond, or re-stated for my specific interest, the work required to de-adhere the liquid?

I haven't been able to find any good resources for macroscale liquid films on solid surfaces. My first guess was surface tension of the liquid multiplied by the interface area; the units work out and it makes some intuitive sense, but I don't like that its independent of the solid material.

Comment: **Every** kind of phase boundary has its own specific surface energy. The value listed in the books for water actually refers to the water-air boundary. You need the value for other interfaces, namely water-glass and glass-air.

Comment: @IvanNeretin A google search for "water glass surface tension" doesn't reveal alternative values. Based on google results, "surface tension seems to be only defined for liquid-gas interfaces. Is there a better term? I suspect something like "surface energy" is better but that doesn't really get me a value either.